# Issue relate to sencha touch bar charts

Tags: sencha-touch

I am very new to sencha touch. Working with sencha touch to develop bar charts. I am an issue regarding the bar width of the chart. As the number of bars get increased the bar width gets decreased. But the thing is it should not happen like that. The bar width must be fixed even if the bars get increased also. I will apply scroll bar to see the reamining bars plotted on the graph. Scroll bar is not issue. But how do I fix the bar width of the bar chart. Could anyone share the solution for this issue ASAP.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Ja...ies/Bar.js.htm

http://docs.sencha.com/touch-charts/1-0/source/Bar.html

http://docs.sencha.com/touch-charts/...art.series.Bar

To change the width of the bar, add the following to your series definition:
e.g.

```
series: [{
      xField: 'comedy',
      displayName: 'Comedy',
     style: {color:0x6238A7, size:8}
       }]
```

see if u can get anything from this

Comment: with this option u can change the bar width but labels are not rendering properly. so you need to use scrollbars for the chart panel to view remaining bars.

Comment: I have checked with the style option in series config but its not working. you specify the bar width in touchcharts-debug.js

Answer (score 0):

bar chart widht is depend on height of your chart's counteiner so you have to set height of counteiner by calculating with number of bar in your chart.
and set calucalted value to counteiner by using setHeight() method